# How do I check if a string is a match *prefix* in C++/Boost regexes?

Tags: c++, regex, stl, prefix

Given lots (millions) of strings and a regular expression object (whether in C++ standard library implementations or in Boost), how can I efficiently<sup>1</sup> detect, for each string, whether it is a valid match prefix?

For example, say if my regex is `^a.*b`, then `ac` is a valid match prefix (because e.g. the superstrings `acb`, `acbcb`, `acbdbebfb`... would match that regex), but `da` is not a valid match prefix.

**Concatenating a sentinel character** is a possible hack, but it's not reliable since I can't control mismatches being detected merely based on the length (rather than dereferencing).

So **I'm hoping** there is a way to inspect the `match_results` object or use other internal machinery to detect this on common implementations (or at least on Visual C++, which I'm on).

<sub><sup>1</sup> There's no hard boundary here, just something common-sense. I have millions of strings to match against, and need it to be fast for the user sitting behind the computer. So I can probably afford a 2x performance hit, but not a 20x one.</sub>

Comment: Why don't you check on `^a.*`?

Comment: @JVApen: Because I don't control what's in the regex...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You're saying I should have the user type in a regex twice, one for prefixes and one for full matches?

Comment: stack overflow isn't much of a "teach me how to do X" or "do X for me" kind of place.       Also, your question is WAY too broad if interpreted one way and is essentially a yes/no question if interpreted literally.  And you don't even define what "efficient" means, so it's not really possible to answer without guessing whether you would consider the answer efficient or not.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating your example? You said that you only have a string prefix, but later refer to string suffixes, and examples don't make that clearer. I think adding some logic quantifiers (exists/for all) and names for strings should help clarity.

Comment: @yeputons: Sure thing, see my edit.